# TSQL: Query to group files by packet of a maximum size

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, packet

I face a problem that could be not very difficult in a first approach but it's not as easy as it could be.
I have a list of files with their sizes in Mbytes that a list from a DB table.

Example:

```
SELECT file_name, file_size
FROM myfiles
```

Result:

```
file_name | file_size    
----------------------
file 1    | 14
file 2    | 5
file 3    | 20
file 4    | 6
```

I want to implement a SQL query that group files by packet to send to an API.
Files should be regrouped by packet of 20 Mb maximum.
The best solution would be to return the "sending index" in a third column.
Something like this:

```
file_name | file_size | packet_index   
-------------------------------------
file 1    | 14        | 1 
file 2    | 5         | 1
file 3    | 20        | 2
file 4    | 6         | 3
```

The first send will contain file 1 & 2, the second file 3 and the last one file 4.
How can I determine this information in SQL please ?

Comment: What if a file size exceeds 20 Mbytes?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that files can't have a file size higher than 20Mbytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this type of problem requires a recursive CTE.  You are assigning groups in order, so:

```
with tt as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by file_name) as seqnum
      from myfiles t
     ),
     cte as (
      select file_name, file_size, file_size as total, seqnum, 1 as grp
      from tt
      where tt.seqnum = 1
      union all
      select tt.filename, tt.filesize,
             (case when tt.filesize + cte.total > 20
                   then tt.filesize
                   else tt.filesize + cte.total 
              end),
             tt.seqnum,
             (case when tt.filesize + cte.total > 20
                   then cte.grp + 1
                   else cte.grp
              end)
      from cte join
           tt
           on tt.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
    )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7a646b5095654aedffab89ba3972b8b1) is a db<>fiddle.

If you have more than 100 rows, then add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. FYI, this query can throw an error like "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.", you should configure "OPTION (maxrecursion 0)" at the end to fix the problem but it could be dangerous and could cause an infinite loop. Be careful about that.

Comment: Re Gordon, it seems it doesn't work with example like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=70b525c2dfd700c834728f2443c21d9c

Comment: I think there is a problem for "case when tt.filesize + cte.filesize > 20", tt.filesize should be the sum of all last previous file size in the current packet and not only the file size of the previous file size.

Comment: @NicoFC34 . . . Fixed.